# Python SSL certificate check hostname according to common name

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I want to check if an hostname and a port according to a SSL certificate. I created this function :

```
@staticmethod
def common_name_check(hostname, port):
    try:
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname)
        s.connect((hostname, int(port)))
        cert = s.getpeercert()
        ssl.match_hostname(cert, hostname)
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

My problem is : When a certificate is expired the verification failed. But the exception is ambiguous :

```
<class 'ssl.SSLError'>
```

I can't know if error is due to certificate expired or bad common name

How can I only check if hostname/port is valid for certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. SSL Error is too generic. I struggled with this too. So you might want to checkout this link.

[Verifying SSL certificates in python](http://blog.san-ss.com.ar/2012/05/validating-ssl-certificate-in-python.html)

Here is a code only answer.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from socket import socket

context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_METHOD) # Use TLS Method
context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2) # Don't accept SSLv2
context.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_NONE, callback)
context.load_verify_locations(ca_file, ca_path)

host = "google.com"
port = 443    #ssl
sock = socket()
ssl_sock = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
ssl_sock.connect((host, port))
ssl_sock.do_handshake()

def callback(self, conn, certificate, err, depth, valid):
    # err here is the error code ([List of error codes and what they mean][2].
    if err == 62:
        print("HOSTNAME MISMATCH!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this. certfile is PEM format.
Not quite the same, as I'm comparing against a certificate file..

```
# Check if the certificate commonName is a match to MYSTRING
certpath = 'c:\cert.cer'
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
cfile = open(certpath,"r")
cert_file = cfile.read()
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file, default_backend())
for fields in cert.subject:
    current = str(fields.oid)
    if "commonName" in current:
        if fields.value == MYSTRING:
            print 'certificate (' + fields.value + ') matches'
        else:
            print 'certificate (' + fields.value + ') does NOT match'
```